# Attempting simple proof of concept of microsoft / RulesEngine but getting JsonSerializationException

Tags: c#, .net-core, rule-engine, jsonserializer

I'm assuming I've made a stupid mistake here, but wondering if someone could assist?

I am trying out the following library:

```
Install-Package RulesEngine -Version 3.2.0
```

My rules.json is as follows:

```
[
  {
      "WorkflowName": "DeliverToMatchingSuburb",
      "Rules": [
        {
          "RuleName": "MatchingSuburb",
          "Expression": "customer.PostCode == location.PostCode"
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

My code:

```
    string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines("rules.json");
    Customer c = new Customer();
    Pharmacy p = new Pharmacy();
    var pharmacies = p.GetLocations();
    var customers = c.GenerateCustomers();

    var re = new RulesEngine.RulesEngine(readText, null);
```

My attempt to pass 'readText' into the RulesEngine however gives me the following exception?

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Unexpected end when reading JSON. Path '', line 1, position 1.'
```

The exception occurs at this line: *var re = new RulesEngine.RulesEngine(readText, null);*

- I have checked that the JSON is valid by using an online JSON
  validator.
- I've also tried adding curly braces at the top and
  bottom.
- I've even tried copy/pasting the example rules JSON from the
  documentation here
  https://github.com/microsoft/RulesEngine#how-to-use-it (knowing
  it won't work but should at least pass the step of creating the
  RulesEngine) but that too fails with the same error.

Comment: It would be better if you provide a code from the static method RulesEngine.RulesEngine(

Comment: @RomanIeromenko: That's part of the library they're using. It's at https://github.com/microsoft/RulesEngine/blob/main/src/RulesEngine/RulesEngine.cs, but it's not entirely unreasonable that the OP isn't aware of that.

Comment: Apologies guys, I should have mentioned where the library was being used in my code snippet etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expectation for the `RulesEngine(string[], ILogger, ReSettings)` constructor is that each element of the string array is a complete JSON object. In your case, you've provided just a single line per array element.

Given that your text file already contains a collection of rules, you should deserialize it yourself, and pass the deserialized collection into the constructor accepting a `WorkflowRules[]`:

```cs
string json = File.ReadAllText("rules.json");
var rules = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WorkflowRules[]>(json);
var engine = new RulesEngine.RulesEngine(rules);
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I think what threw me was the constructor expecting string[], so I thought for some reason I needed to pass even a single rule as a string[].  Somehow I missed the overload(s). Thank you.